# How To use multiline textblock in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

i wants to display my text in to multiline with use of textblock.i have one textblock and it text property is binding with webservices.and run time textblock display on long single line.but i wants to devide this single line in to multiline.
so what i can do? i also use text wrraping property but it is not working.

and my XMAL Code is

```
 <TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="Address:"  Height="Auto"/>
<TextBlock FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Address}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="49,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: Did you try by setting the Width of the TextBlock to a fixed width?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the `Height="Auto" Width="Auto"` .Set fixed values and then set `TextWrapping="Wrap"`

Comment: Thank You Alfah.this answer is very helpfull for me.i got solution perfect solution

Comment: @user1507074 Good to hear, Please mark the answer and close the topic. Thank you.